# join video and music to form a video file

Tags: java, video, audio

I wonder if someone could help me.

I´ve created a video from a set of images using jmf and an already done example .

Now I´d like to add music to my video (.mov or .avi) to generate a new video with the music...

I´ve heard about xuggle api but I don´t know how to do that.

could anyone help me plz?

thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can add audio and other types of tracks to videos using Quicktime Pro.  I wrote a blog post on this a while back ( http://blog.grgcomponents.com/2010/09/13/video-editing-on-a-budget/ ) (which is really just a couple of warnings and a bump to an eHow article).  I was really concerned with chapter lists, but you should be able to use the same process to add audio tracks, I think.

Comment: thanks, but I´d like to do it in java code, any suggestions? thanks again

Comment: Yeah, if you're looking to work with video in Java, Xuggler is your best bet.  They've got an example in their tutorials that encodes sound (though I haven't run it).  It's (yes, really) "How To Grow Some Balls" here: http://wiki.xuggle.com/MediaTool_Introduction#How_To_Grow_Some_Balls